# Prove that $\sqrt{x^{3} + y^{3}+1} + \sqrt{z^{3} + y^{3}+1} + \sqrt{x^{3} + z^{3}+1} \ge 2 + \sqrt{2(x^{3} + y^{3}+z^{3})+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, substitution, karamata-inequality

Given $x, y,z \ge 0$. Prove that 
$$\sqrt{x^{3} + y^{3}+1} + \sqrt{z^{3} + y^{3}+1}  + \sqrt{x^{3} + z^{3}+1} \ge 2 + \sqrt{2(x^{3} + y^{3}+z^{3})+1} $$

---

**Attempt**

Notice that $$(x^{3} + y^{3}+1) + (z^{3} + y^{3}+1)  + (x^{3} + z^{3}+1) = 2 + 2(x^{3} + y^{3}+z^{3})+1  $$

So the sum of squares must be between two forms as below:

$$2 + \sqrt{2(x^{3} + y^{3}+z^{3})+1} \le \sqrt{x^{3} + y^{3}+1} + \sqrt{z^{3} + y^{3}+1}  + \sqrt{x^{3} + z^{3}+1}  \le 2 + 2(x^{3} + y^{3}+z^{3})+1$$

If I work backwards I will get, by letting the form in each root be $a,b,c$ respectively:

$$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}  + \sqrt{c} \ge 2 + \sqrt{a+b+c-2} $$

$$ a + b  +c + 2(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc}  + \sqrt{ca}) \ge 4 + (a+b+c-2) + 4\sqrt{a+b+c-2}$$

$$  (\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc}  + \sqrt{ca}) \ge 1 + 2\sqrt{a+b+c-2}$$

$$  ((\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc}  + \sqrt{ca}) -1))^{2} \ge  4(a+b+c-2)$$

$$ (ab + bc  + ca + 2a^{2}\sqrt{bc} +2b^{2}\sqrt{ac} +2c^{2}\sqrt{ab}) - 2(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc}  + \sqrt{ca}) + 1 \ge  4(a+b+c-2)$$

How to continue?

---

Apart from the attempt above, I have tried:

- AM-GM for the sum of the 3 squares
- AM-GM for the sum of the 3 squares, then using Holder's inequality from the GM
- AM-GM for each square

Comment: From where does it come?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner https://ktom.tomi.or.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+1}\geq2+\sqrt{a+b+c+1}$$ we can prove also by the following way:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+1}-2-\sqrt{a+b+c+1}=$$
$$=\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}-2-\left(\sqrt{a+b+c+1}-\sqrt{c+1}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}-2-\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+b+c+1}+\sqrt{c+1}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}-2-\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+b+1}+1}=$$
$$=\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{b+1}-2-(\sqrt{a+b+1}-1)=$$
$$=\sqrt{a+1}-1-\left(\sqrt{a+b+1}-\sqrt{b+1}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt{a+1}-1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+b+1}+\sqrt{b+1}}\geq\sqrt{a+1}-1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+1}+1}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks. So just by taking conjugates solves the problem..

Answer (score 1):

It should be 
$$ (ab + bc  + ca + 2a\sqrt{bc} +2b\sqrt{ac} +2c\sqrt{ab}) - 2(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc}  + \sqrt{ca}) + 1 \ge  4(a+b+c-2),$$
where $a\geq1$, $b\geq1$ and $c\geq1$, for which it's not so easy to find a proof.

By the way, the Karamata's inequality  helps.

Indeed, let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1},$ $x^3+y^3=c$, $x^3+z^3=b$ and $y^3+z^3=a$.

Thus, $f$ is a concave function and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+1}\geq2+\sqrt{a+b+c+1},$$ which is just Karamata because if $a\geq b\geq c$ so
$$(a+b+c,0,0)\succ(a,b,c)$$ and
$$f(a+b+c)+f(0)+f(0)\leq f(a)+f(a)+f(b)$$ and we are done!

Comment: thanks, but this problem should be solved without Karamata etc. I

Comment: @Arief Anbiya The Karamata's inequality is a trivial enough. Just draw a graph of a concave function.

Comment: Is not Karamata's applies for Convex, instead of Concave function? The $f(x)$ here is concave downward.

Comment: Oh, the otherway of the ineq applies when it is concave down. 
Ok.